# error filtrar array de objetos

Tags: java, array, poo

estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de la Uni de java y soy bastante nuevo en esto la verdad, estoy tratando de hacer un filtro en un array de socios de una biblioteca para saber lo adeudado, desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Al principal lo recorte asi no quede tanto texto, si hace falta algo mas por favor me dicen y edito el post

```
public class SoliPrestamoJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private  List<Libro> libros;
    private AdministradorLibros modelo;
    AdministradorSocios administradorSocios;

    //Aqui esta el problema

  private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

        Integer dni;  
        dni=   Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldDNISocio.getText()) ; 
        dni=   Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldDNISocio.getText()) ;
         System.out.println("La deuda es :" + administradorSocios.filtrarSociodeuda(dni));
        
    }
```

clase AdministradorSocios,intente hacer aquí la código para hacer el filtro de socios.

```
package com.mycompany.tp_2;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AdministradorSocios {

    ArrayList<Socio> socios;
    public AdministradorSocios() {
    }
public void crearArrayList(){

    socios = new ArrayList();
}    
public void insertarSocio(Socio socio){

 socios.add(socio);
}

//aqui esta el problema
public float filtrarSociodeuda(int id){
 float aux = 0;
 for(int c=0;c<socios.size();c++){
//reporte+= socios.get(c).toString();
    if(socios.get(c).dni== id){
    aux = socios.get(c).deuda;
    }
 }

 return aux;
}
public String devolverInformacion(){

String reporte ="";
for(int c=0;c<socios.size();c++){
reporte+= socios.get(c).toString();
}
return reporte;
}

}
```

error
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mycompany.tp_2.AdministradorSocios.filtrarSociodeuda(int)" because "this.administradorSocios" is null`

Edit.

Clase SoliSocioJFrame, En esta clase hago el llenado de la lista de objetos Socio.

```
public class SoliSocioJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    AdministradorSocios administradorSocios;
    
    public SoliSocioJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        administradorSocios = new AdministradorSocios();
        administradorSocios.crearArrayList();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void jButtonRegistrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        
        if(jCheckBoxConfirDir.isSelected()|| jCheckBoxConfirmPago.isSelected()){
        
         // aqui se llena la lista de objetos 
        String nombre = jTextFieldNombre.getText();
        String apellido = jTextFieldApellido.getText();
        Integer  dni;
        dni = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldDNI.getText());
        String direccion = jTextFieldDir.getText();
        

         
        Socio socio= new Socio(nombre,apellido,dni,100,direccion,3);
        administradorSocios.insertarSocio(socio);
        System.out.println(administradorSocios.devolverInformacion());
        
         jLabelerror.setText("Socio registrado con exito");
         jTextFieldNombre.setText("Nombre");
         jTextFieldDNI.setText("DNI");
         jTextFieldDir.setText("Direcccion");
         jTextFieldApellido.setText("Apellido");
        }else{
            
        jLabelerror.setText("Falta chekear algun paso ");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Muéstranos cómo asignas `administradorSocios` en tu clase `SoliPrestamoJFrame` y cómo llenas tu lista de objetos `Socio`, es decir, dónde llamas a `insertarSocio()`, pues algo ha quedado nulo en ese punto, muy probablemente la propiedad `deuda`, que luego intentas obtener aquí: `socios.get(c).deuda`.

Comment: Creo que ya agregue lo que me pedias .Muchas gracias por tu ayuda bro.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: En tu código no veo cómo asignas `administradorSocios` a tu clase `SoliPrestamoJFrame`. Ese campo de la clase no se asigna nunca, por tanto será nulo cuando intentes usarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cosa es que en la clase **SoliPrestamoJFrame** estás declarando el objeto **AdministradorSocios** **administradorSocios**, pero no lo estás instanciando (inicializando o como le quieras decir). El punto es que si no creas el objeto y se lo asignas a la referencia nunca vas a poder usar su método **administradorSocios.filtrarSocioDeuda(dni)**.

Por otro lado, si antes de usar el método **filtrarSocioDeuda(dni)** no usas el método **insertarSocio(Socio)**, para llenar el **Array** que tienes en la clase **AdministradorSocios**, no vas a obtener ningún resultado o te va a dar un error. Espero que esa sea la solución :D